# Slow Airport Extreme -> Cable Modem ping time

Tags: router, ping, airport-extreme

While I currently have the new Airport Extreme router, I had the same problem with my previous router as well (which was a Netgear running dd-wrt).

The setup is extremely basic: I have a cable modem plugged into the router. For some reason, the ping times are usually extremely high between the router and the modem. If I plug a computer directly to the modem (using the same cable), the ping is fine.

Here's a partial traceroute to my ISP. Step 1 is to the router, step 2 is to the cable modem. Notice the jump from 1ms or so up to 500ms or so.

```
$ traceroute teksavvy.com
traceroute to teksavvy.com (206.248.155.70), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  1.580 ms  0.912 ms  0.819 ms
 2  10.124.111.1 (10.124.111.1)  506.422 ms  592.207 ms  596.401 ms
 3  ginispc.wbb.net.cable.rogers.com (24.156.143.81)  627.533 ms  685.005 ms  739.309 ms
 4  24.156.156.1 (24.156.156.1)  692.289 ms  273.782 ms  272.206 ms
```

I do sometimes have torrents going, but this happens regardless of whether they're running or not (this was my first guess!). My instinct is that the cable is flaky, but the same cable plugged into a computer works without issue.

Restarting the router resolves the problem for a minute or two, but then it goes higher again.

Any guidance would be appreciated.